# What is the best way to use SWF library runtime (AIR)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash, swc

I am building a project in AIR that going to run third party SWF. What is the best way to instruct people creating those SWF files?

I don't understand how signing is going to work here. to avoid that I been trying to create a library project in Flash builder 4.7, how ever I do not see an option to export it as SFW file, nor I know a way to share SWC in run time.

So how do I do this?

Comment: I didn't understand who is going to build that library, as you ask how to instruct other to do it, and you are doing it yourself? Who's building the library and what's your exact question - how to use external one, or how to build such?

Comment: I am not the one who is building it. This is going to be published on android. So it need to be signed(My part at least). What about those external swf. They build in air. So does they need to be signed? And if yes than how? If not than how(Flash builder 7 do not let me to publish without signing)?

Comment: It's somehow unclear. If someone builds a library for you, and you **package** the app yourself (building it somehow), this means you can use any kind of library approach - loading external swf, including swc file, importing the code, whatever. If you want to load that on runtime - it won't happen :)

Comment: Of curse I want to load it in run time. lol, Why not?

Comment: I don't see how it's clear that you want to load it runtime - it would be nice if you put all that info inside your question. You cannot load swf and execute code from it on mobile devices - there are many restrictions. Check this out: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/ and also search Google for it.